# I can not import filters in playframework 2.3.0

Tags: scala, playframework, servlet-filters, playframework-2.3

I use playframework 2.3.0, recently I want to add the CSRFFilter

when I import csrf in global.scala:

```
import play.filters.csrf._
```

I get an error for this:

[error] G:\testprojects\app\Global.scala:7: object filters is not a member
   of package play
   [error] import play.filters.csrf._

My plugin.sbt is

```
...
// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.0")
...
```

I use Build.scala instead of build.sbt

```
lazy val root  = Project("root", base = file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
.settings(baseSettings: _*)
.settings(libraryDependencies++=appDependencies)
.settings(
  scalaVersion := "2.11.1",
  version := "1.0"

)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaCsrf) you have to add the filters dependency to your project:

```
libraryDependencies += filters
```

The documentation is for build.sbt but I guess it should work with Build.scala too.

Comment: Note that you will need to `import play.Play.autoImport._` for access to `filters` (Play 2.4.x) - spent a good few minutes trying to figure out why filters wouldn't resolve in my Build.scala

Comment: Actually it is now `import play.sbt.Play.autoImport._`, `play.Play` is deprecated

Comment: @poroszd I am getting the same error where my project is not able to identify either play.sbt or play.filters. Could you please help me identify what I am missing here?  the error I am getting is cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class CORSFilter
  location: class Filters

Answer (score 1):

Play Framework **GzipFilter** is working for me,

my `build.sbt` file

```
name := "GZIP"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  filters
)     

play.Project.playJavaSettings
```

---

```
steps to get play.filters package
1. play
2. update            //important
3. clean
4. eclipse
5. compile
6. run
```

finally it will work.... (update command is important)
   if IDE not detecting **play.filters**
   do the above steps one more time
   **finally copy paste below code**

```
import play.GlobalSettings;
import play.api.mvc.EssentialFilter;
import play.filters.gzip.GzipFilter;

public class Global extends GlobalSettings {
    public <T extends EssentialFilter> Class<T>[] filters() {
        return new Class[]{GzipFilter.class};
    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 1):

In Play 2.4.3, the import is:

```
import play.filters.cors.CORSActionBuilder
```

It's no longer called `csrf`, but `cors`.