# I can not import filters in playframework 2.3.7

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.3

I have seen this same question for scala language, but it didn't help my problem.
[I can not import filters in playframework 2.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257288/i-can-not-import-filters-in-playframework-2-3-0)

I want to add the CSRFFilter but I can't import play.filters.csrf.*;, project doesn't see this class.

Global.java

```
import play.GlobalSettings;
import play.api.mvc.EssentialFilter;
import play.filters.csrf.*;

public class Global extends GlobalSettings {
    public <T extends EssentialFilter> Class<T>[] filters() {
        return new Class[] { CSRFFilter.class };
    }
}
```

build.sbt

```
name := """AppName"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18",
  filters,
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  javaWs
)
```

and plugins.sbt

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.6")

// web plugins

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.0.0")
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If you use IDE such as Eclipse of Intellij, try recreating project with `sbt eclipse` or `sbt idea`.

Comment: It didn't solve the problem, even `activator dependecies`, `activator clean`, `activator update` and `activator eclipse`

Comment: @Adam But your problem is just with the IDE right (ie if you compile using `activator clean compile` you don't get any errors)?

Comment: The problem isn't jusw with the eclipse. I have errors like this
`[error] C:\..\...\..\workshop\..\app\Global.java:3: error:
 package play.filters does not exist
[error] import play.filters.*;
[error] ^`